# Setting a ViewModel boolean property inside a storyboard

Tags: wpf, binding, storyboard

I have a storyboard that's triggered by a property in the ViewModel, this trigger the animation to start.
But how do I set the "Saved" property back to *False* when it is done with the animation (to trigger the ExitAction.)

```
<Style TargetType="TextBlock" x:Key="FadeInOut">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Saved}" Value="True">
                <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Duration="0:0:1" From="0" To="1" />
                            <!-- set "Saved" to false when done -->
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Duration="0:0:1" From="1" To="0"  />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

Answer (score 9):

If you can navigate to your property i would recommend a [BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.booleananimationusingkeyframes.aspx) with a discrete frame at your end-time.

```
<BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames
            Storyboard.TargetProperty="DataContext.Saved"
            FillBehavior="HoldEnd">
            <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame Value="False" KeyTime="0:0:1" />
</BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
```

Since you use a binding to `Saved` i assume using the DataContext should work.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames to set the property. I'm not quite sure if you could use other animations but this is the one I recently used.

```
    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Saved">
        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                <system:Boolean>False</system:Boolean>
            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
```

Comment: Excuse me thos must be set in the EnterAction?

Comment: @advapi: I'm sorry, but I don't understand your question. This might be because I'm not in the .NET universe anymore for years. As far as I remember, this code has to go into a storyboard. Hope that helps.