# WPF trigger can't change a property in mvvm

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, triggers

I wanted to make it happened to change property in ViewModel using `Trigger` tag in xaml.

The code I made was like this.

```
        <Grid x:Name="LogoGrid">
            <Grid.Style>
                <Style TargetType="Grid">
                    <Setter Property="Height" Value="{Binding LogoHeight, Mode=TwoWay}"/>

                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Grid}, Path=ActualHeight, Converter={StaticResource ImageHeight}}" Value="False">
                            <Setter Property="Height" Value="150"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Grid.Style>
            <Image Source="/Resources/Logo/Logo.png" Style="{StaticResource GameWindowLogoStyle}"/>
        </Grid>
```

I bound data to ***LogoHeight*** property in ViewModel and I wanted to set this property to 150 when parents grid is big enough to show Logo Image.

It works fine in the UI. but it didn't change ***LogoHeight*** property.
It is the same things keep happening when I use animation with `Storyboard` tag.

Is it normal things that propery can't be changed by `Trigger` tag or animation in the `Storyboard` tag.

Please tell me the way if there is a way to change property in `Trigger` tag or `Storyboard` tag.

Thank you.

Comment: You can just bind the ActualHeight of the control with Mode=OneWayToSource and use that in you ViewModel

Comment: Since you tagged your question with _MVVM_ I have to tell you that the view related data like height of a control or height in general doesn't belong into the view model. Trigger is the right way to go. But if your control's dimension depends on those of a parent control then bind your trigger to this parent control's property e.g. `Height`. You can use a`IValueConverter`  to perform additional calculations or transformations of this value. The converter can even replace the trigger since a Trigger can't check conditions like "greater than"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `Setter` in a `Style` cannot set the property of a view model. It can only set a property of the element to which the `Style` is being applied, i.e. the `Grid` in this case.

You may be able to work around this by using a `Storyboard` that animates the source property:

[Setting a ViewModel boolean property inside a storyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5647452/setting-a-viewmodel-boolean-property-inside-a-storyboard)

Comment: The idea is to set Height by a Trigger, which in turn is TwoWay-bound to a VM property.